# Are there any workarounds to this spurious VS2010 C++ IntelliSense error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, lambda, intellisense, c++11

Here is some sample code that illustrates the problem.
It **compiles and runs** correctly, but the VS2010 editor IntelliSense complains about the `hold` variable and shows the following message

> IntelliSense: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a
>   specific object

```
class tester
{
public:
    void test()
    {
        int outer[] = {1,2,3};
        int inner[] = {4,5,6};
        std::for_each(outer, outer + _countof(outer), [&](int o) {
            std::for_each(inner, inner + _countof(inner), [&](int i) {
                hold.push_back(i + o);
            });
        });
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> hold;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    tester().test();
    return 0;
}
```

NB: It is happy if there is only one level of for_each (just outer for example)

Has anyone else come across this, and if so, is there a way to change it slightly so that the IntelliSense is happy or am I stuck with red squiggly lines?

UPDATE:
I have downloaded the preview of VS11 it is happy with the code - no squiggly lines, so at least it has been fixed for the next release.

Comment: It is a fairly inevitable side-effect of implementing the statement completion parser with one parser, the one made by the Edison Design Group, and the compiler parser by another, the famously buggy/accepting previous syntax compiler home-grown by Microsoft.  EDG has a knack for getting it right, getting them to agree is a never-ending battle.  Where can I sign to *never* have to work on *that* problem?  Sort of being a rescue worker or police detective, they get to retire after 20 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking for a workaround to placate VS2010's intellisense, you can capture hold in the outer lambda like this:

```
std::for_each(outer, outer + _countof(outer), [&](int o) {
    auto &hold = this->hold; // capturing hold to avoid intellisense reporting an "error"
    std::for_each(inner, inner + _countof(inner), [&](int i) {
        hold.push_back(i + o);
    });
});
```

Explicitly define hold's type or rename the variable for clarity as you feel is appropriate (using auto and name hiding due to laziness).